# Cut-list members in simulation

Tags: solidworks

I created a structure using weldments, but when I do a new static study the cut-list members are in folders. I want to select them all and change them from beams to solid bodies. My question is why the members appear in folders and sometimes they don't. I have over 100 member, and it's really frustrating to expand all the folders and select them.

Comment: Hello and welcome to GD.SE. This is not a graphics design question I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because thei belongs to [Engineereing.se](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @joojaa Hmmm, interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, right click on the cut-list folder and delete it to get all the members out of the cut-list folder.